# rewrite url blog.php/?slug=test-blog to blog/test-blog

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

How to rewrite url blog.php/?slug=test-blog to blog/test-blog using rewrite rule in htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must capture part of the query string in a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) and use that in the [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

```
RewriteEngine on

# prevent endless loop    
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# redirect to pretty url
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} slug=(.+)
RewriteRule ^blog.php$ /blog/%1? [R,L]

# serve real content
RewriteRule ^blog/(.+)$ /blog.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Comment: it adds blog/test-blog?slug=test-blog and shows 404 not found page

Comment: @Vicky I forgot to append a question mark `?` and it seems you need both ways. Please see updated answer.